# Deserialize multi JSON string with Play JSON library

Tags: json, scala, web, playback

I'm writing a server that need to parse JSON strings uploaded by clients. Currently I'm using Play JSON lib. For example:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

def parseJSON(jsonString: String) = {
    val jsv = Json.parse(jsonString)
    jsv
}
```

Considering a client uploaded a JOSN string of `{"key1": 1}`. After the server received the entire string, just simple invoke the `parseJSON`method, everything will be done.

However, if a client uploaded TWO JSON strings, `{"key2": 2}` and `{"key3": 3}`, and due to the bad network, these two JSON strings reach the server at the same time. The server will get a long string of `{"key2": 2}{"key3": 3}` (The server can not know it contains two JSON strings before parsing). if I invoke the `parseJSON` method and pass the entire string, only the first JSON value `{"key2": 2}` will be returned. The second one `{"key3": 3}` will be ignored.

So, how can I parse the second JSON string? Is there a way to know how many Chars are used when parsing the first JSON string?

Comment: If you're ingesting a stream of JSON properly its probably not going to be a trivial endeavor [Scanning a HUGE JSON file for deserializable data in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365694/scanning-a-huge-json-file-for-deserializable-data-in-scala)

Answer (score 0):

```
val jsonString2 = """{
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": 2
    }
    {
    "key3": 3,
 """
```

I think this is not valid JSON value, please make your question cleaner as possible so we can help :)